# Centered items in NSCollectionView

Tags: objective-c, center, osx-mountain-lion, nscollectionview, nscollectionviewitem

I'm developing a simple gallery for an application for OS X, by default, the items of a `NSCollectionView` are in left, How I get its items centered in its width? like this image: [image: iPhoto]

Comment: Hey!, I don't know how to do that but I found an useful repo [here](https://github.com/indragiek/OEGridView). This is my [result](http://cl.ly/LlMJ)

Answer (score 0):

Set up your prototype view to contain an instance of NSImageView (assuming that's what you're using to display your pictures) that's the size of the prototype view itself. Set up the image view so that it resizes with the prototype view. Then, using the Attributes inspector, set the alignment to the center.